# Compute maximum likelihood estimates for various ngrams

Tags: python, nlp

I have built a trigram model for a test corpus that I want to calculate the maximum likelihood estimates of.

Suppose we have the following text:

```
text = "The white fox, The white fox, the black fox."
```

Its trigrams will be: `(The white fox), (white fox The), (fox The white) ...`

To do so I will have to calculate all the occurrences of let's say 'white' and then all the occurrences of trigrams ending in 'fox' and followed by 'the white', 'the black' and so on.

Is there a better way of doing is other than iterating over all of the trigrams, splitting them and reading their contents to see if they are what I need for the current iteration?

*I know about nltk, but this is for learning purposes and I'd rather see how it is done myself.*

Comment: Use KenLM, or SRILM.

Answer (score 0):

In short, I would say no. Iterating through every tri-gram can seem laborious and inefficient but it is vital if you are wanting to generate text from given probabilities. In my personal opinion I would recommend using a bi-gram system due to the difficulty of generating anything feasible with a tri-gram. Unless using a very good source of data, I think you will yield better results with the simple dual-probabilities method. Have a think about what you want to achieve and whether you have the necessary resources for a tri-gram system